# How to add author information to published gradle module metadata

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

When i run the `generateMetadataFileFormMavenPublication` task, i get a json at `build/publications/maven/module.json` which is missing these fields: name, description, minimumCoreVersion, title, version, author. IntelliJ prompts me to add them back in. The author (developer) is present in the generated pom file. What am i missing to also add this (and the other required fields) to the `module.json` file?

It seems like an oversight from gradle, because from their examples (and from my own experience) its sufficient to just add this to publish a jar:

```
publishing { publications { maven(MavenPublication) {
  groupId project.group; artifactId project.name; version project.version
  from components.java;
} } }
```

Here is the groovy code i am working with:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            pom {
                name = project.name
                description = (project.name + ' description')
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id = 'daveankin'
                        name = 'Dave Ankin'
                        email = 'daveankin@gmail.com'
                        organizationUrl = 'https://example.com'
                    }
                }
            }
            groupId project.group
            artifactId project.name
            version project.version

            from components.java
            withBuildIdentifier()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need an Manifest file to specify author.
I am using task like this:

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
            "Class-Path": sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.asPath,
            "Main-Class": "MainClass",
            "Implementation-Title": project.name,
            "Implementation-Version": archiveVersion,
            "Implementation-Vendor": "Specify Author here",
            "Build-Jdk": org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current(),
            "Gradle-Version":GradleVersion.current().toString()
    )
  }
  duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
  from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
```

}

I hope that it will help you.
Also you can look at the Oracle specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JARManifest

If you will use similar task like above then actor's name will be stored in MANIFEST file. Manifest file will be added to result JAR archive

Comment: my question was pertaining not to the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file but the gradle file. I would be surprised if affects the output of the gradle `module.json` file, but if I try it I will report back here.

Comment: @DaveAnkin I think it will not affect module.json file... Looks like I didn't follow your problem well